# window.location not working as required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to redirect to a location like **(site name)/p/(some 4 digit code)**.

I tried using:

```
window.location.href = "/p/(code)"
```

when the above didn't worked I tried the following:

```
$('#search-product-code').click(function(){
    var lookUp = $('#product-search-input').val();
    if (lookUp > 999 && lookUp < 9999) {
        console.log(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/p/" + lookUp);
        if (window.location.port == "") {
            window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/p/" + lookUp;
        } else {
            window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + "/p/" + lookUp;
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting different problems on UAT and localhost.

On UAT the url changes from : 
https://(sitename)/in-store to https://p/(code)

On local :
https://localhost:9002/in-store to https://localhost:9002/p/undefined/p/(code)
the **/undefined/p/** part is appended each time I try to run above code like https://localhost/p/undefined/p/undefined/p/(code).

Both the methods above are providing me with same results.

Comment: you probably need to add `<base href='(your site base path)'>` element to your index.html

Comment: "when the above didn't work"  That should work just fine, provided you have the correct value for `code`.  What actually resulted when you tried that?   Unless you're redirecting to a different server, setting the protocol and hostname manually is unnecessary. (A `<base>` tag is also unnecessary unless you need to work with a base url other than server root.)

Comment: @DanielBeck The results were same in both the approaches.

Comment: You're saying that setting `window.location.href="/p/(code)"` resulted in the url `https://p/(code)`?  Are you running this in a web browser?

Comment: @DanielBeck yes, I have no clue how that is happening because there are many places where we are using window.location.href and they all work fine except this one.

Ran it on firefox and crome

Comment: The only way I can imagine getting the results you're describing is if the `window` object was absent or redefined, which shouldn't be possible. Are you running this in a web browser, or are you in some sort of offline testing or serverside rendering environment  that doesn't define `window`?

Comment: I am running it on the latest build for firefox developer edition and google chrome

Comment: What does that `console.log` in your code output?

Comment: Are you trying to stay in the same domain? `window.location.pathname = '/p/(somecode)' `

Comment: @Iscmaro yes I am trying to remain in the same domain.

Comment: @AayushRohatgi - then that code I commented with should work.

Comment: console log - https://localhost/p/9000.
But browser then also logs - Navigated to https://localhost:9002/p/undefined/p/9000

Comment: Your value is not set, hence it is undefined. I'd post a complete code example for a better answer. HTML + JS

Comment: window.location.pathname = '/p/(somecode)' tries this too, same results. @Iscmaro I am using only 1 variable that is lookUp which can be undefined and that is giving the value i.e 9000. I dont know what is undefined there.

Comment: It's the port or your lookUp variable, one or the other then. console log your `window.location` object just after your click and see what you're missing.

Comment: try replacing window.location.href = "/p/(code)" with window.location.href = "~/p/(code)"